# query order dosen't seem to be working in capped collection & C driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm a newbie in using mongodb, I'm trying to use it for logging information on a BeagleBone Black system using mongodb version 2.4.10 supplied by the debian jessie distribution that I ams using on the BBB. I'm using [the third-party driver "libmongo-client"][1] that is supplied by debian to interface from my application to mongodb, rather than the official MongoDB C Driver.

My problem is that I'm trying to display documents in the reverse order to what they were inserted in. I have my own time field, right now an int64 that is milliseconds from the epoch. I specify a search:

```
        query = bson_build_full(BSON_TYPE_DOCUMENT, "$orderby", true,
                            bson_build(
                                       BSON_TYPE_INT64, "time", -1,
                                       BSON_TYPE_NONE),
                            BSON_TYPE_NONE);
```

I've tried changing the 'order' from -1 to 1, but the results are always in the original insertion order.
I've searched the list here and can't find any results that seem to be germain. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

After posting the comment below, I tried changing the query to:

```
        query = bson_build_full(BSON_TYPE_DOCUMENT, "$sort", true,
                            bson_build(
                                       BSON_TYPE_INT64, "$natural", -1,
                                       BSON_TYPE_NONE),
                            BSON_TYPE_NONE);
```

same result, everything was returned in the order it was inserted into the database.  I then looked at the query and decided I didn't know what the type of the "$natural" should be, so I changed it to INT32, and I got no documents returned. So at least I've gotten some reaction from the database to what I'm asking for.

[1](https://github.com/algernon/libmongo-client) link added by A. Jesse

Added 20150402
Here is the complete code for both of the queries that I'm currently doing:

```
    if (dbET_ALL == filter)
{
    query = bson_build_full(BSON_TYPE_DOCUMENT, "$query", true,
                            bson_build(BSON_TYPE_INT64, "", 0,
                                       BSON_TYPE_NONE),
                            BSON_TYPE_DOCUMENT, "$orderby", true,
                            bson_build(BSON_TYPE_INT64, "time", -1,
                                       BSON_TYPE_NONE),
                            BSON_TYPE_NONE);
}
else
{
    query = bson_build_full(BSON_TYPE_DOCUMENT, "$query", true,
                            bson_build(BSON_TYPE_INT32, "entrytype", filter,
                                       BSON_TYPE_NONE),
                            BSON_TYPE_DOCUMENT, "$orderby", true,
                            bson_build(BSON_TYPE_INT64, "time", -1,
                                       BSON_TYPE_NONE),
                            BSON_TYPE_NONE);
}
bson_finish(query);
```

I sometimes want all of the entries and sometimes only 1 type. I added the "$query" to the first one as suggested by A. Jesse with the blank "" name to allow it to compile. The second query with the filter is working correctly but I always get the results back in oldest to newest order.

Comment: I've tried adding another element to the query, "$sort" on the same field, neither 1 or -1 effects the order of the output. Also changing the "$orderby" to $order" had no effect.  How do I tell if I'm even supplying elements that the query recognizes?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB queries require a `$query` field if you include a special field like `$orderby`. In the shell:

```
> db.capped.find({$orderby: {time: -1}})
> db.capped.find({$orderby: {time: -1}, $query: {}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("551b10fe10de18a796aaf279"), "time" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("551b10fc10de18a796aaf278"), "time" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("551b10f810de18a796aaf276"), "time" : 0 }
```

I don't know the syntax for `bson_build_full` but I expect you need something like this to append the empty `$query` document?:

```
    query = bson_build_full(
            BSON_TYPE_DOCUMENT, "$orderby", true,
                        bson_build(
                                   BSON_TYPE_INT64, "time", -1,
                                   BSON_TYPE_NONE),
            BSON_TYPE_DOCUMENT, "$query", true,
                        bson_build(BSON_TYPE_NONE),
                        BSON_TYPE_NONE);
```

Comment: I tried adding a blank query as your suggested and the compiler got mad that it didn't match the prototype for a bson_build(). I then tried filling out the query with a name of "", but got the same results.  I've also been using a query to filter on another field and even with that I get the same oldest to newest order. I'm going to have to edit my original question to add the full code, so see above.